# How to know the Physical Application Path in Window Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

We have a .Net 2.0 Site and we are moving it to a Windows Azure Website.

Our site needs some config parameters (via web.config > appSettings). One of them is the physical address (For example: \boswinfs05\home\users\web\b2614\whl.clientname\ or d:\sites\single57\clientname\webroot).

In our actual hosting we get it in the Panel Control but I can´t find it in the Azure Portal.

Someone knows how to get it in Azure Portal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never know it before your site is actually deployed and run.

You can get it runtime and initialize static property of some class during Application_Start event. I believe your web site does nothing before Application_Start.

Comment: But actually to do the deployment and run our site we need to give it the pshysical path... Actually we have the Windows Azure url but we are getting a "The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred."

Comment: Then you have to change how your application starts and initializes ... And to understand why your site fails, go through [Troubleshooting: Windows Azure Websites](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/best-practices/troubleshooting-web-sites/)

Comment: Ok.. We will do it.. We´ll change the app. Thanks!!